# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Timestamp' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, object, dart, timestamp, null-check

I have a model who have "date" as a final parameter .

```
class WalletTransaction extends Equatable {
    final String id;
    final String amount;
    final String description;
    final bool isDepense;
    final Timestamp date;

  WalletTransaction(
     {required this.id,
     required this.date,
     required this.amount,
     required this.isDepense,
     required this.description});
```

I want to pass an instance of this model class so i did a null check operator to check if the variables is null or not

```
AddWalletTransactions(
    new WalletTransaction(
        amount: amount ?? "00",
        date: date ?? Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()),
        isDepense: isDepense ?? true,
        description: description ?? "",
        )
        )
```

But the it gives me this problem in **Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now())** :

> The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Timestamp'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (probably) lies in your `date` object. I'll also assume you're using `Timestamp` from `firestore`.

In Dart, the `??` operator is evaluates to the left-hand-side if it is non-null, otherwise the right hand side.

However, when calculating the static type of that expression, it can only choose a type that both sides are valid for. For example:

```dart
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

final a = dog ?? Animal();
// a has a static type of Animal

final b = 'world' ?? 'hello';
// b has a static type of String

final c = Scaffold() ?? 'hello';
// c has a static type of Object
```

In general, Dart chooses the most specific type that both sides match.  In the Dog/Animal example, `Object` would also be a valid static type for `a`, but so is `Animal`, and `Animal` is more specific, so `Animal` is chosen.

In your example, you use:

```dart
date ?? Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now());
```

The static type of `Timestamp.fromDate(...)` is `Timestamp`, and (I'm assuming) the static type of `date` is `DateTime`.

These 2 types are not related at all, and so the most specific type that is valid for both is `Object`, so Dart gives that expression a static type of `Object`.

If you want to create a `Timestamp` from a date that may or may not be null, you can simply move the `??` inside the `Timestamp`:

```dart
date: Timestamp.fromDate(date ?? DateTime.now())
```

or you can use a ternary operator with 2 `Timestamp` instances:

```dart
date: date == null ? Timestamp.now() : Timestamp.fromDate(date)
```

IMO the first option is slightly cleaner